# CUDA C++ class is mistaken for template

Tags: c++, cuda

I define a class. I want to add some texture with my ray-tracing code with CUDA. And I use new when call the constructor.

```
#ifndef TEXTURE_H
#define TEXTURE_H

#include "RTnextweek.h"
#include "vec3.h"

class texture
{
public:
    __device__ virtual vec3 value(float u, float v, const vec3 &p) const = 0;
};

class const_texture : public texture
{
public:
    __device__ const_texture() {}
    __device__ const_texture(vec3 c) : color(c) {  }

    __device__ virtual vec3 value(float u, float v, const vec3 &p) const
    {
        return color;
    }

public:
    vec3 color;
};

class checker_texture : public texture
{
public:
    __device__ checker_texture() {}
    __device__ checker_texture(texture *t0, texture *t1) : even(t0), odd(t1) {}

    __device__ virtual vec3 value(float u, float v, const vec3 &p) const
    {
        float sines = sin(10 * p.x()) * sin(10 * p.y()) * sin(10 * p.z());
        if (sines < 0)
            return odd->value(u, v, p);
        else
            return even->value(u, v, p);
    }
public:
    texture *even;
    texture *odd;
};

#endif
```

and the compiler reported:

```
nvcc main.cu -o texture.exe
main.cu
E:\texture.h(7): error: argument list for class template "texture" is 
missing

E:\texture.h(14): error: argument list for class template "texture" is missing
......
11 errors detected in the compilation of "main.cu".
```

I didn't even define a template but the complier report the template wrong. What's wrong with my code? Why this problem happen?

Comment: At a glance, it seems like `texture` is a templated type

Comment: thanks, but I try this code in ordinary C++ using shared_ptr and succeed complied and run...So I give up CUDA...

Comment: `texture` is indeed a named (and templated) type in CUDA.  Just call your class something else, like `my_texture`

Comment: I didn't expected that...thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not well documented, `texture` is a templated class for the C++ runtime API (for example [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL.html#group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL_1g67c786e4e84d7b9a1f5efc4d56784483)). It is defined in an internal header which is automagically included by nvcc during its pre-processing stage.

If you rename your texture type to something else, the problem will disappear. For example:

```
typedef float3 vec3;

class text
{
public:
    __device__ virtual vec3 value(float u, float v, const vec3 &p) const = 0;
};

class const_text : public text
{
public:
    __device__ const_text() {}
    __device__ const_text(vec3 c) : color(c) {  }

    __device__ virtual vec3 value(float u, float v, const vec3 &p) const
    {
        return color;
    }

public:
    vec3 color;
};

class checker_texture : public text
{
public:
    __device__ checker_texture() {}
    __device__ checker_texture(text *t0, text *t1) : even(t0), odd(t1) {}

    __device__ virtual vec3 value(float u, float v, const vec3 &p) const
    {
        float sines = sin(10 * p.x) * sin(10 * p.y) * sin(10 * p.z);
        if (sines < 0)
            return odd->value(u, v, p);
        else
            return even->value(u, v, p);
    }
public:
    text *even;
    text *odd;
};
```

will [compile without error](https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/Y7efn4).